# Get time left from now with giving time of tomorrow in 24 format in javascript

Tags: javascript, compare

Happy new year everyone,,

I'm using this function to get the time left between today and giving date (Hours:Minutes) and it works fine...

```
function PrayerTimeLeft(prayerTime){
    var today = new Date();
    var prayerTimeDate = new Date();
    prayerTimeDate.setHours(prayerTime.substring(0,2));
    prayerTimeDate.setMinutes(prayerTime.substring(3,5));
    var diffMs = (prayerTimeDate - today);
    var diffHrs = Math.round((diffMs % 86400000) / 3600000);
    var diffMins = Math.round(((diffMs % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000);
    return {
        getDiffMin:function(){
            return diffMins;
        },
        getDiffHrs:function(){
            return diffHrs;
        }
    };
}
```

I can use it like this:

```
var test = new PrayerTimeLeft("14:00"); // and today was 12:00 in 24 format
console.log(test.getDiffHrs()); //It will show 2 hours
```

I'm here trying to get how many left for a coming Prayer time, there are five Prayers: First: 5:00 
Second: 11:42 
Third: 14:26 
Fourth: 16:50 
Fifth: 18:07

My problem is if the current time (let's say it will 23:00) is between fifth and first one, here we are talking about tomorrow time which is between (5:00 & 18:07)

I can't realize this reverse things?

Comment: It's very unclear what you are trying to do. How can you expect the code to know if "5:00" is meant to be 5:00 today, 5:00 tomorrow, or 5:00 any other day?

Comment: @76484 I'm here trying to get how many left for a coming Prayer time, there are five Prayers:
First: 5:00
Second: 11:42
Third: 14:26
Fourth: 16:50
Fifth: 18:07

My problem is if the current time (let's say it will 23:00) is between fifth and first one, here we are talking about tomorrow time which is between (5:00 & 18:07)

I hope now is clear?

Comment: If you want to obtain the time until the *next* prayer time, why are you passing the prayer time to the function? It sounds like the prayer times should be a static configuration (hard-coded values).

Comment: @76484 I've the time of the next prayer, i just need how many left from current time to reach the next prayer time...please check kurideja's answer it works fine and just need to be sure about (%) in minutes, sometimes it gives me double big number.

Comment: I am glad kurideja's answer worked for you (although I think there is a formatting problem when the resulting number of minutes < 10). However, I would like to add that I think the design of your solution could be improved. I think you should not return an object from `PrayerTimeLeft`, but simply return a result. More importantly, I would pass both the from time and the to time to the function so that the method can be easily tested without the dependency on "now". The way I would design this solution can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/76484/Luxqqdvu/

Comment: I am sorry for bugs in formatting. I was rushing to my train and did not test my code much.

I agree that prayer times could be hardcoded. The whole object should be a module (self executing function) with main functions returned in an object (like it's done now). Programming and mastering patterns is a long journey and I suggest practicing them as soon as you start writing more complex objects. Here is the pattern we use at my workplace: http://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/

Comment: @76484 Thank you for your and **kurideja** time, actually i was knew about hours and minutes in formatting if they are < 10, i just need the hours and minutes separated as well so no need to type 01 hour or 09 minutes. About the prayers time they're not fixed numbers, they are changable based on the location and selected method which are modules giving the results to **PrayerTimeLeft** module as well. I've just learned programming in modules in javascript so i found it'll be great if i used them in real projects, it's really helped me! +1 to urls :) Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 3 suggestions:

1. Return only references to functions. Your pattern becomes messy with, let's say, 4+ methods.
2. If you are sure you'll get a string HH:MM, why don't you simply split it?
3. Avoid setting secondary variables just like you did. If you already have primary values (`today` and `prayerTime`) and you are able to derive various new measures (like hours, min, secs etc. left) leave your object as stateless as you can.

Some other patterns would suggest declaring functions AFTER the return statement (instead of declaring `var`s and anonymous `function`s)

```
function PrayerTimeLeft(prayerTime) {
    var today = new Date();
    var prayerTimeDate = new Date();

    var setPrayerTime = function() {
        var prayerHours = prayerTime.split(':')[0];
        var prayerMin = prayerTime.split(':')[1];
        if (today.getHours() >= prayerHours) {
            prayerTimeDate.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
        }
        prayerTimeDate.setHours(prayerHours);
        prayerTimeDate.setMinutes(prayerMin);
    };

    var getDiffMin = function() {
        return (prayerTimeDate - today) / 1000 / 60;
    };

    var getDiffHrs = function() {
        return Math.floor((prayerTimeDate - today) / 1000 / 60 / 60);
    };

    setPrayerTime();

    return {
        getDiffMin: getDiffMin,
        getDiffHrs: getDiffHrs
    };
}
```

And testing:

```
var test = new PrayerTimeLeft("00:00"); // and today was 12:00 in 24 format
    console.log(test.getDiffMin()); //It will show total minutes left
    console.log(test.getDiffHrs()); //It will show total hours left (without minutes) 14:59 left will be shown as 14 hours left (15 hours would be more inaccurate).
```

EDIT: If you want to return HH:MM, here is a snippet with extra function.

```
function PrayerTimeLeft(prayerTime) {
    var today = new Date();
    var prayerTimeDate = new Date();

    var setPrayerTime = function() {
        var prayerHours = prayerTime.split(':')[0];
        var prayerMin = prayerTime.split(':')[1];
        if (today.getHours() >= prayerHours) {
            prayerTimeDate.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
        }
        prayerTimeDate.setHours(prayerHours);
        prayerTimeDate.setMinutes(prayerMin);
    };

    var getDiffMin = function() {
        return (prayerTimeDate - today) / 1000 / 60;
    };

    var getDiffHrs = function() {
        return Math.floor((prayerTimeDate - today) / 1000 / 60 / 60);
    };

    var getDiffString = function() {
        return Math.floor(getDiffMin() / 60) + ':' + getDiffMin() % 60;
    }

    setPrayerTime();

    return {
        getDiffMin: getDiffMin,
        getDiffHrs: getDiffHrs,
        getDiffString: getDiffString
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you, what if i need to get the left time in this format (HH:MM)?

Comment: You're a life saver! Thank you for your time to giving this answer, i've made a little changes to fit my needs, let me share it with users here **[on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8gapc3q/)**, i'm still checking it with all hours and minutes, there is (%) i think sometimes it will show double numbers in minutes section, it's appeared to me just once i don't know why, what do you think?

Happy new year.

Comment: I've added Math.round to minutes, please check it again **[jsFidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbanna/nzsqdv7g/)**